# Where should I store server build logs?

Tags: server, logging

When I build an Ubuntu cloud VPS (typically DigitalOcean), I have a manual build guide that I have written and maintain. As part of the build guide, I leave myself notes on the server in text files so I can see where I got to, what is done, what needs to be done, and so forth. These text files live in `~/.build/` and a typical filename is `310-build-nginx`. The `310` part is a marker for my build guide, so I know it's chapter 3, part 1, section 0. The file is updated at that part of the build is completed, and the builder (i.e. me) is tagged. It's a basic audit log, essentially.

Until now, it's just me building servers. As of today, I have help and `~/.build/` is no longer appropriate for these build status files. The logical place to put these files is in a `/var/log/` location somewhere. I can create a new directory easily enough, but I would prefer to follow convention if there is a preferred directory for these system build files.

Notes:

- there are two system builders, I am one, I trust the other person;
- both accounts have `sudo` rights;
- both accounts have the same build guide;
- edit/addendum: the save location should be on the server itself, in the local filesystem;

Where should I write my system build status files to, please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Graham: I should have been more specific, I was asking if there was a preferred or conventional location _in the local filesystem_ rather than outboarding to another server or provider. I will update my question.

Comment: You can check the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml). I guess anything under `/var` is OK.

Comment: Thank you @Melebius - that works for me. My approach of using `/var/log/[something]` looks sound according to https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05s10.html#specificOptions24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The logical place to put these files is in a `/var/log/` location somewhere.

That would be the perfect place.

The other option would be to store logs inside your project directory.

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind - much appreciated.